# What to do with short-curcuit 18650

Tags: batteries, safety, short-circuit

I was soldering wires to 18650 batteries, and while I was soldering the + tip at one of them, it suddenly became very hot. I thought that maybe some drip of tin get under the tip and shorted it, so I took voltmeter and it measured no voltage, so the cell must be shorted. As it was getting hot and I wasn't able to find any drip of tin which shorted it, I just throwed the cell into iron bucket filled with water.

Is this what I should do? Or what am I supposed to do if this will happend again?
Thanks

Comment: lithium + water is fairly similar to sodium + water, which you can probably find on youtube. You were lucky ... this time.

Comment: To add: The fact you had time to throw it away means two things: 1. You were not just lucky, you were extremely lucky. 2. The cells are probably off-brand knock-offs, unable to deliver the "professional grade" currents, but also not very well built. Step one for next time: DO __NOT__ SOLDER unprotected cells unless you have something close enough to a blast cage to do it in.

Answer (score 4):

No, you are not supposed to do any of that.
It is not good idea to solder directly to li-ion battery, as li-ion batteries really hate heat.
And it is not good idea to extinguish li-ion battery by water. You can use sand.

Comment: In general yes, water reacts with lithium but I'd rather have a lithium battery under 30 cm of water than right next to me on the bench. You don't move away several kg of water that easily without a C4-like explosion.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to buy a simple 18650 battery holder, cheap enough.

[image]

The proper way to connect wires to the battery terminal would be using a **[spot welding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIR3Sd91YHs)** machine. This process takes only a fraction of a second (to weld the wires to the terminals) and the battery would not be heated up as opposed to soldering.

In your case buying a holder would be the safest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing a single cell into a bucket full of cold water isn't actually that bad of a thing to do.

Because lithium battery powered vehicles are becoming more and more relevant, there have been [investigations](http://www.dekra.de/c/document_library/get_file?uuid=920bcb1a-f569-4fd6-80d5-6f4414f871f8&groupId=10100) (German document, sorry) on how to extinguish a burning car filled with lithium ion batteries.

You actually cannot extinguish a burning cell, as the oxygen required for the exothermal reaction is generated inside the cell due to thermal runaway and decomposition of the materials inside the cell, so even putting it in sand will not extinguish the fire. It will just prevent the spread of the fire.

What is the benefit of using water then? For a single cell it's probably not as relevant as in a battery pack. In a battery pack the water will cool down the other cells and prevent decomposition in those cells. That way some cells remain "intact", at least they won't burn. Another point for water is that stuff getting out of the cell (fumes, electrolyte) is bound in the water. But it was noted that you need a lot of water.

---

Do not solder lithium batteries which don't have a solder contact. You will introduce heat very close to the internal chemistry of the cell. It is very likely to damage the separator with excessive heat which occurs during soldering, thus creating an internal short circuit which leads to thermal runaway.

Even if you have cells with solder contacts, make sure to be quick about soldering it.

You were probably lucky that the cell was not fully charged when that happend, otherwise the reaction would have been more furious.